# For what values of $n$ can {1, 2, . . . , n} be partitioned into three subsets with equal sums?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For what values of n can {1, 2, . . . , n} be partitioned into three subsets
with equal sums?

I noticed that somehow the sum from 1 to n hast to be a multiple of 3 and the common sum among these 3 subset is this sum divided by 3, but it's still not a convincing argument. How do you prove there exists 3 subsets of operands such that their sum evaluate to this number?

My solution made from other solutions

Theorem: The given set can be partitioned into three subsets with equals sums whem $\sum_{i = 1}^{n}i  = \frac{1}{2} n(n+1) \equiv 0 \mod 3$ except when $n = 3$ , so $n \equiv 0,2 \mod 3$

Here are some cases which will be important to prove our theorem
 n = 5 $\{1,4\},\{2,3\},\{5\}$
 n = 6 $\{1,6\},\{2,5\},\{3,4\}$
 n = 8 $\{8,4\},\{7,5\},\{1,3,6\}$
 n =9 $\{9,6\}, \{8,7\}, \{1,2,3,4,5\}$

Also note that if $n \equiv  0,2\mod 3$ then $n \equiv 0,2,3,5 \mod 6 $ and ${5,6,8,9}$ represents this modularity, so we can start creating subsets with equal sums with the last 6 elements of the n elements. Once we are done with this 6 elements, we continue with the next 6 until we get to 5,6,8 or 9 and then we apply the base case.

Comment: It's obviously not true for $n=3$, although $1+2+3$ is a multiple of $3$.

Comment: its not hard to prove that it is possible for $n$ large and $n\equiv 0,2\bmod 3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum of all the numbers from $1$ to $n$ is $\frac 12n(n+1)$.  As you say, we need this to be a multiple of $3$, which will be true when $n \equiv 0,2 \pmod 3$.  We can't do $n=2$ or $n=3$, which we can prove by inspection.  For $n=5$ there is $\{1,4\},\{2,3\},\{5\}$ and for $6$ we can do $\{1,6\},\{2,5\},\{3,4\}$.  For larger $n$ it should be "obvious" that you have so much flexibility that it will be possible.  To prove that, we can do $8$ and $9$ by hand, which I leave to you.  Then you can do blocks of $6$ down from the top $\{k+1,k+6\},\{k+2,k+5\},\{k+3,k+4\}$ until you have $5,6,8,9$ left and use the solution we have for that.  Now that you have groups of three sets with the same sum, take one out of each group to form one of the sets with sum $\frac 13 \cdot \frac 12n(n+1)$

Comment: Thanks for the help. I didn't quiet understand what you meant by do blocks of 6. What I can see is that you can start from n which will be 0 mod 3 or 2 mod 3 and greedily pick the next number , so the sum is <= to k and then do this for next the number. At the end, we should get three subsets with equal sum.

Comment: @TheMathNoob It is not that... It is picking the last and 6th last number into the 1st set, the 2nd last and the 5th last into the 2nd set and the 3rd and 4th last into the 3rd set, then going down to the next group of 6 etc. until we are left with 5,6,8 or 9 numbers only. In my answer above there is a different way to sort out those groups of 6, but the idea is similar.

Comment: what is the next group of 6 I have the first group for n = 11 A  ={11,6}, B = {10,5}, C = {9,4}

Comment: Or, in other words: you just stop when you reach 5,6,8 or 9, and do each of those in a bespoke way. (Though, really no need to stop at 6 when you can consume the last six the same as all the other ones.) BTW @TheMathNoob, the first group for $n=11$ is the last six, grouped as {11,6},{10,7},{9,8} rather than the one in your comment.

Comment: ok now I get what you are doing, but why 6? and how do you know that we will always encounter a 5,6,8 or 9?

Comment: Six because it repeats nicely.  It is a multiple of $3$ so does not change the remainder upon dividing by $3$.  Then $5,6,8,9$ represent $5,0,2,3 \bmod 6$ and we said we could't do $1,4 \bmod 6$ (by saying we couldn't do $1 \bmod 3$), so if we subtract $6$s off any large number we can do we come to one of $5,6,8,9$

Comment: Sorry and how did you infer that if 1+....+n is divisible by 3 then $n \equiv 0,2 \mod 3$?

Comment: Because the sum is $\frac 12n(n+1)$ so you need either $n$ or $n+1$ to be divisible by $3$

Comment: One last thing. I noticed that the  sum has to be divisible by 3, but why can't it be divisible by 3?

Comment: edit : One last thing. I noticed that the  sum has to be divisible by 3, but why can't it be divisible by other number?

Comment: 3 is prime, so if it divides $\frac {n (n+1)}{2} $ it must then divide $n (n+1)$, so it must divide either $n $ or $n+1$.

Comment: No, I mean how do we know we don't miss anything.

Comment: I got the solution. I posted my understanding of it.

Answer (score 3):

If $n=6k$, make the following subsets:

$$1,4,\cdots,3k-2,3k+3,3k+6,\cdots,6k$$
$$2,5,\cdots,3k-1,3k+2,3k+5,\cdots,6k-1$$
$$3,6,\cdots,3k,3k+1,3k+4,\cdots,6k-2$$

If $n=6k+r$, where $r=5,8,9$, reduce to the previous case by first partitioning the set $\{1,2,\cdots,r\}$ and then partitioning the $6k$-element set $\{r+1,r+2,\cdots,n\}$ the same as above, except that each set is “translated upwards” by $r$ (all elements increased by $r$).

Example: partition $\{1,2,\cdots,11\}$: $r=5, k=1$ so we first partition $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ into $\{1,4\},\{2,3\},\{5\}$, partition $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ into $\{1,6\},\{2,5\},\{3,4\}$, “translate” the latter upwards by 5: $\{6,11\},\{7,10\},\{8,9\}$ and finally join them to get $\{1,4,6,11\},\{2,3,7,10\},\{5,8,9\}$.

The above construction works for any $n\ge 5$, $n\equiv 0$ or $n\equiv 2 \mod 3$. Cases $n=2$ and $n=3$ have no solutions, and neither have the cases $n\equiv 1 \mod 3$, because in those cases the total sum $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ is not divisible by $3$.

Comment: why did you make the assumption of if n = 6k

Comment: I first solved the case $n=6k$, then solved the general case *using* the case $n=6k$

Answer (score 1):

Clearly we need $n\equiv 0,2\bmod 3$ for the sum to be a multiple of $3$.

We need two disjoint sets with sum $s=\frac{n(n+1)}{6}$.

For the first set $A$ take $1,3,5,\dots$ until the next number would exceed $s$.

For the second set $B$ take $2,4,\dots $ until the next number would exceed $s$.

How many numbers have not been used?

the sum of the remaining numbers is at least $a=\frac{n(n+1)}{6}$ and so there are at least $\frac{n+1}{6}$ remaining numbers.

In other words the numbers $\underbrace{n,n-1,\dots}_a $ are unused.

We can use these numbers to fix $A$ and $B$.(more on this when Im up to it)

Comment: three subsets right?

Comment: well, the complement of the other two gives the third